# Is it better to sort a long list, or many small sub lists?

Tags: python, sorting, grouping

I have a task involving grouping a list of entries by a certain key, then sorting it by another key, and then processing the sorted entries for each of the former keys.

Now, I could just sort the whole list first, and then do the grouping later, or I could do the grouping first and then sort each of the smaller lists.

Is there in general a rule of thumb that can tell me which approach would be faster, or doesn't it matter?

Just going from the complexity of the standard sorting algorithms `O(n log n)`, we can see that

`1000 * log 1000 > 100 * (10 * log 10)` (assuming that the list is separated into 100 groups with 10 elements each), so it appears that sorting many small lists should be much more efficient. Does that translate into actual behaviour of programs?

I am asking this for Python, but I think this is in principle interesting for other languages as well.

Comment: How much resources does your *grouping* action consume?

Comment: Would it be possible just try to run 2 versions and compare with some samples?

Comment: the best way would be to measure different approaches (e.g. using timeit) and then you make sure how it behaves. But in general - grouping should be a one-pass, then sorting smaller lists should be quicker

Comment: @Daweo I don't really know; this is more a theoretical question.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small Python program to test my assumptions, which outputs the following with 3 mio. list elements and 100 groups:

```
Sort first:  4.790350902010687
Group first:  3.902348858071491
```

When I experiment with various list sizes, it looks like the difference becomes more pronounced when the list gets larger.

So grouping first *is* faster than sorting first. Using `O(n log n)` as sorting complexity, the speed factor between the two implementations should be
`log(3000000) / log(30000)` (The whole list has 3 mio entries, each group has 30,000 entries), which is (for all log bases) `1.4467`.

`3.9 * 1.4467 = 5.6`, which is quite a bit more than the actual runtime `4.79`. Which might be caused by some overhead of the sorting algorithm.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from random import randint
from timeit import Timer

num_runs = 1
data_size = 3_000_000

# Data: (index, sorting field, grouping field)
test_data = [ (i, randint(0, 1000000), randint(1, 100)) for i in range(data_size)]

test_data1 = test_data[:]
test_data2 = test_data[:]

def sort_first():
    test_data1.sort(key=lambda e: e[1])
    groupings = defaultdict(list)
    for (i, t, g) in test_data1:
        groupings[g].append((i,t))

def group_first():
    groupings = defaultdict(list)
    for (i, t, g) in test_data2:
        groupings[g].append((i,t))
    for k in groupings:
        groupings[k].sort(key=lambda e: e[1])

duration1 = Timer(sort_first).timeit(number = num_runs)
avg_duration1 = duration1 / num_runs
print("Sort first: ", avg_duration1)

duration2 = Timer(group_first).timeit(number = num_runs)
avg_duration2 = duration2 / num_runs

print("Group first: ", avg_duration2)
```

Comment: It doesn't matter in your test since you used only one run, but runs of `sort_first` beyond the first will operate on an already sorted list.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, I realized that and limited the number of runs to one.